# Microsoft Forms docking to top-left. C#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, winforms, panel

I'm fairly new to programming and this is my first Forms program.

I'm trying to place buttons inside a panel in a manner that they get automatically sorted by alphabetical order.

At first I was trying with a FlowLayoutPanel, which displayed the buttons with the correct size and placement, but not sorted by Alphabetical order:

[With FlowLayoutPanel. Ideal Size and placement, but no sorting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RvJo.png)

I also had a few problems while trying to automatically scale it to screen size.

After failing with a FlowLayoutPanel, I tried just a normal panel. It fixed all my previous problems, but would stretch the buttons when docked:

[With a normal panel. Perfect sorting and scaling, but stretching.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTPd3.png)

Here is the code, if it matters:

```cs
Button modButton = new Button();
modButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
modButton.Name = skinName;
modButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
modButton.TabIndex = 0;
modButton.Text = skinName;
modButton.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
modButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
modButton.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
modButton.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Left;
modButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.modButton_Click);
modButton.TextImageRelation = System.Windows.Forms.TextImageRelation.ImageAboveText;
this.panel2.Controls.Add(modButton);
modList.Add(skinName);
```

And for the panel:

```cs
this.panel2.AutoScroll = true;
this.panel2.AutoSize = true;
this.panel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
this.panel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(636, 450);
this.panel2.TabIndex = 7;
```

Comment: Since when Controls are *automatically sorted in alphabetic order*? Based on what, the Text or the Name? That's something you do, coding it. The two images you're showing only suggest different anchors or docking mode or simply a default behavior of a Container Control. It's not clear what you are asking. You have to learn how anchoring and docking works in different containers, plus how each type of container works. Each has its own specifics. It requires some testing (quite a lot, actually).

Comment: When I first tested a normal panel instead of a FlowLayoutPanel, all the buttons on the right side, for example, got sorted in alphabetical order. I used to have another button above "Apply All" called "Apply selected". Once I put them inside a panel and docked them to the bottom, Apply All immediately got above the other one, and "Import mod folder", that was above all, became the one at the bottom. No matter the order I docked them in, they always seemed to sort themselves that way, so I assumed it was alphabetical order.

Comment: Think you're problem might be related to the Z Order of your buttons.  Have a play around with the Bring to Front & Send to Back functions on the designer

Comment: If you want to make button "dock to top-left", try to set its `Anchor` property `button.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left;`(This is also the default value of Anchor), rather than `Dock`. Besides, what is "Alphabetical order"? The "control order" seem to be the same in the screenshots you provided.